# how to set to OldValue the primefaces selectOneMenu programmatically

Tags: java, primefaces, selectonemenu

Java / PrimeFaces 3.5

I would like to rollback primeFaces selectOneMenu Old Value and reload it updating the component at screen.

1. The selectOneMenu is loaded with FIRST, SECOND , THIRD values and default value is setted with FIRST
2. If I change the selectOneMenu value From FIRST to THIRD, I would like to set it to FIRST again.

   ```
   <p:selectOneMenu id="statusProposta"
      value="#{propostaBean.propostaComercial.proposta_Status}"
        items="#{propostaBean.statusProposta}"
        valueChangeListener="#{propostaBean.regraStatusProposta}" >
        <p:ajax  event="change"  
          process="statusProposta" update="statusProposta" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{propostaBean.statusProposta}" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>
   ```

**StatusProposta :**

public enum StatusProposta { FIRST,SECOND and THIRD .....

***Bean  :***

```
public void regraStatusProposta(ValueChangeEvent ev){
   **I dont know how to set the old value and update it in screen.**
   ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to rollback ?Explain.

Comment: I need to set to OldValue the selectOneMenu and update the oldvalue in the screen @Makky

Comment: If you keep doing that then whats point of selectOneMneu?

Comment: when Im going to be to change the value to a new one clicking on it, the old value has to be setted and updated on selectOneMenu component screen

Comment: oh so you want to display the last selected value somewhere when a user select different value ,right ??

Comment: @BalusC Would you please help me about this  ?thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=36447

resetinput

blog post: Reset Values for JSF 2.2

posted by Howard at primefaces forum

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf

```
public void reset() {  
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("form:panel");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void regraStatusProposta(ValueChangeEvent ev){    
//get old value first 
Object oldValue=ev.getOldValue();    
}
```

[More on ValueChangeEvent API](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent.html#getOldValue%28%29)

Comment: Thats no make sense. where will I set oldValue in the component ? you are setting just an oldValue Object.

Comment: @Al2x I think you either very new to Java or its your bad day today. This makes sense dude. You get the old value now its upto you where you assign it . We're here to help you not to complete your whole assignment.

Comment: I set my entity property to the oldValue and update it with ajax but the new value keeps on the component screen

Comment: 1. The selectOneMenu is previously loaded with FIRST,SECOND AND THIRD values. when I load my form it comes with default the FIRST one. 2- If I choose THIRD value, I need my bean set the default selectOneMenu value to FIRST again automatically and refresh the component at screen. got it ?

Comment: @Al2x Why would you want your selectOneMenu to go back to FIRST value again ,explain that?

Comment: Its my business rule. If customer select one option differente from what is expected I need to set the component with the old value again. got it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've created this utility for PrimeFaces which checks if the component is visible, otherwise it would log a WARN on console.

```java
public static void resetUIComponents(String... componentsId) {
    for (String id : componentsId) {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(id) != null) {
            PrimeFaces.current().resetInputs(id);
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```java
ViewUtils.resetUIComponents("form:id1", "form:id2")
```